# How can I shorten my jQuery snippet?

Tags: jquery

I've tried a lot to shorten my snippet but nothing is working for me.

Here it is:

```
var logoTitle = $(".logoTitle");

logoTitle.children(".char3, .char4").delay(300).each(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        'margin-top':'0', 
        'opacity':'1'
    }, 330, "easeOutQuart");
});

logoTitle.children(".char2, .char5").delay(600).each(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        'margin-top':'0', 
        'opacity':'1'
    }, 330, "easeOutQuart");
});

logoTitle.children(".char1, .char6").delay(900).each(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        'margin-top':'0', 
        'opacity':'1'
    }, 330, "easeOutQuart");
});
```

How can I make this shorter and increase efficiency?

Comment: Did any of these answers help you? Let us know by an upvote or correct answer.

Comment: thanks for the help! all answers are helpful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want this to run immediately, like your original script:

```
(function animateLogoChildren(theChildren, theDelay){
    var logoTitle = $(".logoTitle");

    logoTitle.children(theChildren).delay(theDelay).each(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            'margin-top':'0', 
            'opacity':'1'
        }, 330, "easeOutQuart");
    });
})(".char3, .char4", 300);
```

If you want this to run on a call:

```
function animateLogoChildren(theChildren, theDelay){
    var logoTitle = $(".logoTitle");

    logoTitle.children(theChildren).delay(theDelay).each(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            'margin-top':'0', 
            'opacity':'1'
        }, 330, "easeOutQuart");
    });
}

animateLogoChildren(".char3, .char4", 300);
animateLogoChildren(".char2, .char5", 600);
animateLogoChildren(".char1, .char6", 900);
```

The second is most likely what you're looking for, given how I cleaned up the code. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the each function.  This makes it more "efficient" if your definition of efficient is download.  But speed wise there is not much you can do.

```
var logoTitle = $(".logoTitle");

logoTitle.children(".char3, .char4").delay(300).animate({
        'margin-top':'0', 
        'opacity':'1'
    }, 330, "easeOutQuart");
logoTitle.children(".char2, .char5").delay(600).animate({
        'margin-top':'0', 
        'opacity':'1'
    }, 330, "easeOutQuart");
logoTitle.children(".char1, .char6").delay(900).animate({
        'margin-top':'0', 
        'opacity':'1'
    }, 330, "easeOutQuart");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd be looking to make a custom animation function to allow reuse of the code, something like:

```
var logoTitle = $(".logoTitle");

$.fn.myAnimate = function(delayTime) { 
    return $(this).delay(delayTime).each(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            'margin-top':'0', 
            'opacity':'1'
        }, 330, "easeOutQuart");
    })
}

logoTitle.children(".char3, .char4").myAnimate(300);
logoTitle.children(".char2, .char5").myAnimate(600);
logoTitle.children(".char1, .char6").myAnimate(900);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var logoTitle = $(".logoTitle");

function animate_kids(kids, delay) {
    kids.delay(delay).animate({
            'margin-top': 0,
            'opacity': 1
        }, 330, "easeOutQuart"); 
    });
};

animate_kids(logoTitle.children(".char3, .char4"), 300);
animate_kids(logoTitle.children(".char2, .char5"), 600);
animate_kids(logoTitle.children(".char1, .char6"), 900);
```

Let me know if you have any questions. Good luck! :)